# Why is this selection on a ForEach in SwiftUI not working?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Can someone please tell me why this selection isn't working?
If I click one of the rows of the `ForEach` nothing happens :/

```swift
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ContentView.manufacturerByName)
var manufacturers:FetchedResults<Manufacturer>

@State private var selection: Manufacturer?

Section("Manufacturer") {
    List(selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(manufacturers, id:\.self) { manufacturer in
            Text(manufacturer.name ?? "--")
        }
        .onDelete { rows in
            for row in rows {
                let manufacturer = manufacturers[row]
                storageProvider.deleteManufacturer(manufacturer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `.onDelete` method works fine.

what I want to achieve is that when a manufacturer-row is clicked,

- that there is a check mark in the row
- and the variable "selection" should be set to the manufacturer

---

*I know that apps for the use of tobacco are not allowed in the AppStore. This is just an app to learn.*

`MyApp.swift`

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let storageProvider = StorageProvider.standard
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(storageProvider: storageProvider)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, storageProvider.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

`ContentView.swift`

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CodeScanner

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    let storageProvider: StorageProvider
    
    // Tobacco
    @State var tobaccoName: String = ""
    @State var tobaccoNr: String? = nil
    @State var ean: String? = nil
    
    // EAN
    @State private var isPresentingScanner = false
    @State private var scannedCode: String?
    
    // Manufacturers
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ContentView.manufacturerByName)
    var manufacturers: FetchedResults<Manufacturer>
    
    @StateObject var searchText = SearchText()
    @State private var selection: Manufacturer?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section("Tobacco Details") {
                TextField("Name", text: $tobaccoName)
                TextField("Number (e.g. #017)", text: $tobaccoNr ?? "")
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                HStack {
                    TextField("ean", text: $ean ?? "")
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    Button {
                        isPresentingScanner.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text(selection?.name ?? "no selection") // <-- here
            Button {
                storageProvider.saveManufacturer(named: "Test")
            } label: {
                Text("create manufacturer")
            }
            Section("Manufacturer") {
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(manufacturers, id:\.self) { manufacturer in
                        // -- here, use a Label
                        Label(manufacturer.name ?? "--",
                              systemImage: selection == manufacturer ? "checkmark" : "circle")
                    }
                    .onDelete { rows in
                        for row in rows {
                            let manufacturer = manufacturers[row]
                            //  storageProvider.deleteManufacturer(manufacturer)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("add Tobacco")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        
        // MARK: - EAN-Scan Sheet
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingScanner) {
            CodeScannerView(codeTypes: [.ean13], showViewfinder: true) { response in
                switch response {
                case .success(let result): do {
                    ean = result.string
                    isPresentingScanner = false
                }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
        
        // MARK: - Bottom Button
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    if selection == nil {
                        print("no manufacturer")
                    } else {
                        storageProvider.saveTabacco(
                            named: tobaccoName,
                            number: tobaccoNr,
                            ean: ean,
                            manufacturer: selection
                        )
                        dismiss()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("save Tobacco")
                        .font(.callout)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .contentTransition(.identity)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding([.horizontal, .top])
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
        }
        
        // MARK: - Manufacturer Search-Filter
        .onReceive(searchText.$debounced) { query in
            /// don't filter when searchbar is empty
            guard !query.isEmpty else {
                manufacturers.nsPredicate = nil
                return
            }
            /// set filter when someone searches
            manufacturers.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Manufacturer.name), query])
        }
    }
}

func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
        set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 }
    )
}
```

`StorageProvider.swift`

```swift
public class StorageProvider {
    
    public static var standard = StorageProvider()
    public let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    
    public init() {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Core Data store failed to load with error: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}



// MARK: - Functions to call from the Views
public extension StorageProvider {
    func saveTabacco(named name: String, number: String?, ean: String?, manufacturer: Manufacturer?) {
        let tabacco = Tabacco(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        tabacco.name = name
        tabacco.number = number
        tabacco.ean = ean
        tabacco.manufacturer = manufacturer
        tabacco.creationDate = Date.now
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
            print("Tabacco saved succesfully")
        } catch {
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
            print("Failed to save Tabacco: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func saveManufacturer(named name: String) {
        let manufacturer = Manufacturer(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        manufacturer.name = name
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
            print("Manufacturer saved succesfully")
        } catch {
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
            print("Failed to save Manufacturer: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func getAllTabaccos() -> [Tabacco] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Tabacco> = Tabacco.fetchRequest()

    do {
      return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch {
      print("Failed to fetch tabacco: \(error)")
      return []
    }
  }



  func deleteTabacco(_ tabacco: Tabacco) {
      persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(tabacco)
      
      do {
          try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
      } catch {
          persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
          print("Failed to save context: \(error)")
      }
  }
    
    func deleteManufacturer(_ manufacturer: Manufacturer) {
        persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(manufacturer)
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
            print("Failed to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func updateTabacco(_ tabacco: Tabacco) {
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            persistentContainer.viewContext.rollback()
            print("Failed to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - FetchRequest

extension ContentView {
    static var tabaccosByName: NSFetchRequest<Tabacco> {
        /// create Request
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Tabacco> = Tabacco.fetchRequest()
        
        /// sortDescriptor
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Tabacco.name, ascending: true)]
        return request
    }
    
    static var manufacturerByName: NSFetchRequest<Manufacturer> {
        /// create Request
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Manufacturer> = Manufacturer.fetchRequest()
        
        /// sortDescriptor
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Manufacturer.name, ascending: true)]
        return request
    }
}
```

---

#### Workaround

```swift
Section("Manufacturer") {
    List() {
        TextField("search for manufacturer", text: $searchText.text)
        
        if manufacturers.isEmpty {
            if searchText.debounced != "" {
                NavigationLink(destination: CreateManuView(storageProvider: storageProvider, manuName: searchText.text)) {
                    Label("add **\(searchText.text)**", systemImage: "plus")
                        .tint(.accentColor)
                }
            } else {
                Text("search for a manufacturer to add")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
        
        ForEach(manufacturers) { manufacturer in
            Button(action: {
                selection = manufacturer
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(manufacturer.name ?? "--")
                        .tint(.primary)
                    Spacer()
                    if manufacturer == selection {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        .onDelete { rows in
            for row in rows {
                let manufacturer = manufacturers[row]
                storageProvider.deleteManufacturer(manufacturer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Selection works in editing mode. Consult docs.

Comment: I added an EditButton() - still not working in editing mode.

Comment: `clicking` on a row only selects the row, you then have to `swipe` right to left to trigger the `delete`. Your code works well for me in my test.

Comment: The delete works well.

What I want (perhaps I have not clarified this correctly) when a row is clicked is...

* see a checkmark next to the row (selection)
* and get the selected object into the selection variable
(to use the object again later)

Comment: There is no `checkmark` in your code, are we suppose to dream this up. The selected object **is** set into the `selection` variable, that is its purpose. You can see that
 if you add `Text(selection?.name ?? "no selection")` above the `Section("Manufacturer")`

Comment: sry... I thought it adds an checkmark with the selection.
Don't know why I thought this^.

But also the selection is not working for me with this code :/
Did you try it yourself?

I added the `Text(selection?.name ?? "no selection")`. If I add an `.onTapGesture { selection = manufacturer }` to the text, then the selection is working for me.

Comment: But when I do it with an `.onTapGesture` I wouldn't need the `selection: $selection` or the `id:\.self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code that shows a `checkmark` when a row of the list is selected, and
shows that the `selection` variable contains the `List(selection: $selection)`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // for testing
    // @State var manufacturers = [Manufacturer(name: "one"), Manufacturer(name: "two"), Manufacturer(name: "three")]

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Manufacturer.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
     private var manufacturers: FetchedResults<Manufacturer>
    
    @State private var selection: Manufacturer?
    
    var body: some View{
        Text(selection?.name ?? "no selection") // <-- here
        Section("Manufacturer") {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(manufacturers) { manufacturer in
                    // -- here, use a Label
                    Label(manufacturer.name ?? "--",
                          systemImage: selection == manufacturer ? "checkmark" : "circle")
                }
                .onDelete { rows in
                    for row in rows {
                        let manufacturer = manufacturers[row]
                        //  storageProvider.deleteManufacturer(manufacturer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: first of all, thank you! - second... could my problem be, that the object (Manufacturers) has no id? or that it is not Identifiable? I just created my Entity in the model editor.

Comment: if your `Manufacturer` that you don't want to show, has no `id`, make sure it is `Hashable`, and it will work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTgy2.png

This is how I created my `Manufacturer` in Core Data.
I'm just learning to use Core Data so i don't know if it is `Hashable` :/

Comment: I added a id (UUID) now, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: With coredata you should not have to add an id, or Hashable. Can you show the code you are using rather than some bits of it. Have you tried my code as it is. What error do you get? What is the `problem` that you have?

Comment: updated my answer with a possible CoreData `FetchRequest`. Does this not "work" for you?

Comment: I added most of my code above.

Comment: You can find my FetchRequest on the bottom of the `StorageProvider.swift`

Comment: No thanks, I don't do chat. Explain what the problem you have now? What error do you get? Does the `Text(selection?.name ?? "no selection")` not show what you expect?

Comment: My main problem is, that the selection doesn't work. If I click on one row the added `TEXT` (which you have thankfully suggested) doesn't change.

Comment: [GIF of the problem](https://imgur.com/a/wGbaxVg)

Comment: I added a working workaround above which uses a button to set the current selection. But I don't know if this is how I should do it.

Comment: try commenting the `Form{` (not the content of it). Do you get the `checkmark`?

Comment: YES ! The `Form{}`is the problem :/

Comment: That's really f*** up

Comment: great, you are up and going now.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! - I'm using the workaround I added in the first post above.

Answer (score 1):

**Environment**: Xcode 14+, Swift 5+

Apple Doc would tell us to use:

```
List(manufactures, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { ... }
```

But for using List's **selection** feature with **Sections**, the best approach IMO is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var manufacturers: [Manufacturer] = [
        Manufacturer(name: "Adidas"),
        Manufacturer(name: "Nike")
    ]
    @State private var selection: Manufacturer?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            Section("Manufacturer") {
                ForEach(manufacturers, id:\.self) { manufacturer in
                    Text(manufacturer.name ?? "--")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // Console checking purpose only:
                            print(selection)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried this one, and it always prints `nil`- could my problem be, that the object (Manufacturers) has no id? or that it is not Identifiable? I just created my Entity in the model editor.

Comment: Actually you should use **\.id** instead of \.self when the collection used in the List/ForEach has this property. However, the focus of your question was in the List's **selection** behavior. I created a dumb Manufacturer struct to solve the issue. Another tip: You should verify that Core Data fetching call you implemented, because it's a little bit strange: check @workingdog support Ukraine implementation for that.

Comment: I added more of my code. You can find the implementation of the FetchRequest on the bottom of the `StorageProvider.swift`